# Adding a float whole number into InfluxData.Net as field throws exception assuming it is an integer

Tags: c#, .net, influxdb

I'm using `<package id="InfluxData.Net" version="8.0.1" targetFramework="net462" />`

In this [Issue](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/3032) it is said that

> all numbers are now floats unless explicitly declared integers during writes (with a trailing i #3526). Closing as no longer relevant.

But when I add a field with a Key `FloatValue` and Value - float without decimal places it throws exception

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (InfluxData API responded with status code=BadRequest, response={"error":"partial write: field type conflict: input field \"FloatValue\" on measurement \"forests\" is type integer, already exists as type float dropped=4"}
>   )'

Here is a printscreen: [image]

Any solutions to fix the adding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I recieved the float **as an object** and immedietly assigned it to the Point, although the field value expects an object I needed to cast it to float first.